# catch http.call timeout exception

Tags: meteor

This Meteor server code uses http@1.2.8, during slow internet connection it prints the below to the terminal:

```
response = HTTP.call(method, url, {
  timeout: 30000,
  headers: header,
  content: content,
  followRedirects: true
});
```

> Exception in callback of async function: Error: ETIMEDOUT
>    at Object.Future.wait (/abc/xyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0.i9pn2o++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)

How do I gracefully catch this error so that I can inform the client? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a try catch

```
try{
    response = HTTP.call(method, url, {
        timeout: 30000,
        headers: header,
        content: content,
        followRedirects: true
    });
}
catch(e){
    if(e.code==="ETIMDOUT"){
        //alert the client
    }
}
```

Comment: When i throw the error to the client, will the error still look the same as on serverside?